# How to replace more than one element at the same time in a String (Haskell)

Tags: string, list, haskell, replace

i want to take 2 lists for example like this;

```
find=["Hou","House","Mouse"]
repl=["Mou","Bird","House"]
```

So when i give a text like that;

```
"The House with Mouse is big"
```

Output should be this;

```
"The Mouse with House is big"
```

So i wrote this;

```
replace :: String->String->String->String
replace _ _ []=[]

replace find repl text
  = if take(length find) text == find
      then repl ++ replace find repl (drop (length find) text)
      else [head text] ++ (replace find repl (tail text))

replaceMore ::[String]->[String]->String->String
replaceMore _ _ []=[]
replaceMore _ [] _ =[]
replaceMore [] _ _ =[]
replaceMore find repl text
  = if (tail find) == [] || (tail repl)==[]
      then text
      else replaceMore (tail find)
                       (tail repl)
                       (replace (head find) (head repl) text)
```

It returns

```
"The Mouse with Mouse is big"
```

so it doesn't work like how i want and i think the problem is here;

```
replaceMore _ _ []=[]
replaceMore _ [] _ =[]
replaceMore [] _ _ =[]
```

But still i have no idea how to fix this.So any Ideas?

Comment: **Make it easy for people to help you.** Don't just say “it doesn't work”: say *how* it doesn't work. **If there are error messages,** copy+paste them into your question. **If the code runs but gives the wrong answers,** then give examples of: input your code takes, incorrect output your code gives back, correct output you want your code to give back.

Comment: No, your problem is not where you think it is. The entire idea is wrong. You cannot build `replaceMore` out of `replace`. You need to search for all patterns in parallel, and replace the first one found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might give you some ideas towards the working algorithm.

First of all, you need to divide your input `String` into parts (`[String]`) according to your `find` strings. So this function is

```
divideIntoParts :: [String] -> String -> [String]
```

which works something like

```
divideIntoParts find "The House with Mouse is big"
```

gives

```
["The ", "Hou", "se with ", "Mouse", " is big"]
```

So it extracts the parts to replace from the string, but preserves the order of letters by keeping other parts in the same list. The naive implementation might look like this

https://gist.github.com/Shekeen/5523749

Next you'll need a function to scan through this list and replace the parts, which need to be replaced. The signature will be

```
replaceParts :: [String] -> [String] -> [String] -> String
```

which works like

```
replaceParts find repl $ divideIntoParts find "The House with Mouse is big"
```

will be

```
"The Mouse with House is big"
```

So your full `replace` function will look like

```
replacePatterns :: [String] -> [String] -> String -> String
replacePatterns find repl = (replaceParts find repl) . (divideIntoParts find)
```

Also you really need to implement a faster substring search algorithm and consider replacing `find` and `repl` with one `Data.Map`

Comment: How can i write divideIntoParts function without help of Data.List.Split .I am novice so i couldnt get over the "return value" problem.I mean the function returns [String] so i cant do something like-> else [[head text] ++ divideIntoParts find (tail text)]

Comment: The main idea is to find the leftmost substring in your input string, which matches a string from `find`. Then you'll get your string divided into three parts: before matched substring, matched substring, after matched substring. Then you do the same recursively, but apply it to the part after matched substring. I'll update my answer with actual code later, but I think you'll get the idea.

Comment: yeah i understood the algorithm i thought about it aswell but i couldn't write the function because of the "type  match error".The function returns [String] i have to bind the unmatched part together and its String.I have to do String ++ String so how am i going to do that recursively? i'd be very glad if you update your code because i have no idea how to write this algorithm

Comment: I have implemented a naive version of `divideIntoParts` function. You can see it here https://gist.github.com/Shekeen/5523749

Answer (score 0):

There are two bugs I can see:

1. The final elements of `find` and `repl` are always ignored. `replaceMore` gives back `text` when `tail find == []` or `tail repl == []`; that should be when `find == []` or `repl == []`.

   But they should be caught by the earlier equations

   ```
   replaceMore _ [] _ =[]
   replaceMore [] _ _ =[]
   ```

   which, you should be able to see now, are wrong, and should be

   ```
   replaceMore _ [] text = text
   replaceMore [] _ text = text
   ```
2. But then the output would be

   ```
   "The House with House is big"
   ```

   Still wrong. This is because you are building `replaceMore` out out `replace`. For each search term, you search through the text, replacing it when found. So you replace `"Hou"` with `"Mou"` (so `"House"` is replaced by `"Mouse"`); and then later you replace `"Mouse"` with `"House"` (meaning that what was originally `"House"` ends up as `"House"` again).

   Instead you should search through the text once, looking for every search term at a position before advancing through the text.